# Why are HMAC signatures frequently used for webhook authorization but not other HTTP API requests?

Tags: http, api, hmac, security-by-design

HMAC signatures are very commonly used for webhook authorization from service to consumer.

Examples:

- [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)
- [Slack](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack)
- [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-security)
- [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/account-activity-api/guides/securing-webhooks)
- [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/using-webhooks/validating-webhook-deliveries)

and hundreds and hundreds more. This seems a near universal design decision.

Yet, the other direction (consumer to service) never uses HMAC signatures. The mechanism varies, but in some cases secrets are put directly in headers.

Why is HMAC so strongly preferred for service to consumer HTTP messages, but not consumer to service?

Comment: In consumer to service scenarios, it's not uncommon for HMAC signatures to be used to sign the request.  AWS uses this method (see https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html).

Comment: @mti2935 it is uncommon. The AWS API is one of the few exceptions.

Comment: Another example is Binance's API.  See https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv3order.